# Set index of dropdown list to value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list

```
   <label for="staffType">Staff Type<br /></label>
      <select id="myList" name="staffType" onchange="show()">
        <option>Care Staff</option>
        <option>Nursing Staff</option>
        <option>Administrator</option>
      </select>
```

I want to set the index to $user['staffType'].

what is the best way?
the php code to create the user object

```
<?php while ($cursor->hasNext()):
$user = $cursor->getNext(); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set the value"? Set what value?

Comment: i'm pulling a value from a db (eg Administrator) and populating a form which has a dropdown for user type. I want to set the index of the dropdown list to the value from the db

Comment: what does "$user['staffType']" it holds?

Comment: string eg "Administrator"

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code where you create the drop-down?

Comment: <?php while ($cursor->hasNext()):
    $user = $cursor->getNext(); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Depdending on how you set your dropdown values, you need to give a condition to set if the corresponding value matches, if yes, then set it to selected. Consider this example:

```
// from db values
$values_from_db = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'staffType' => 'Care Staff'),
    array('id' => 2, 'staffType' => 'Nursing Staff'),
    array('id' => 3, 'staffType' => 'Administrator'),
);

// current value to be checked
$user['staffType'] = 'Administrator';

// i don't know how your select box values are rendered
<label for="staffType">Staff Type<br /></label>
<select id="myList" name="staffType" onchange="show()">
<?php foreach($values_from_db as $key => $value): ?>
    <option <?php echo ($value['staffType'] == $user['staffType']) ? 'selected': ''; ?> ><?php echo $value['staffType']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```